# (Qt 5.7) xcoder123/SimpleSmtp_SSL_QT5 giving errors

Tags: qt, github, smtp, qsslsocket

I've downloaded a project from github with the intension of learning SMTP and SSL. However, once i try to run his project, i receive the following errors:

- "qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_client_method"
- "qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_CTX_new
  "
- "qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init"
- "qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error"
- error  "QAbstractSocket::SocketError(21)"
- "qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error
  "
- "error  QAbstractSocket::SocketError(20)"

---

The "AbstractSocket" Errors are:

- SocketError(20): The SSL library being used reported an internal error. This is probably the result of a bad installation or misconfiguration of the library
- SocketError(21): Invalid data (certificate, key, cypher, etc.) was provided and its use resulted in an error in the SSL library.

---

I know that for the project to work you need OpenSSL. But i think in Qt 5.7 it is a default library or something like it.

[This](https://github.com/xcoder123/SimpleSmtp_SSL_QT5) is the page of the project.

Is there something I am missing? Do I need to install OpenSSL?

---

EDIT: I installed OpenSSL from [This](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) website. Its a pre-compiled version. Also, I moved the DLL's found in `C:\OpenSSL - Win64` to my build folder

Comment: do you have openssl installed?

Comment: I actually don't know. I downloaded from "shining Lights Production" the pre-compiled 64 bits version. I only ran the installer. So yeah, it is installed but i didn't messed with it.